# How to per-write a value in certain heap address?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, heap-memory, ubuntu-14.04

I am using GDB(peda-gdb) to debug a program, can I write something in a heap address so when the program reach that address It can read it out? I know the address but I do not know how to write something in that address. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to the heap using C syntax, with commands that evaluate an expression like `print` or `set var`.  For example, to write an integer value to a specific location:

```
(gdb) set var *(int *)0xYOURADDR = 23
```